# Escape [0] in ImageMagick label

Tags: imagemagick

I am generating a number of imagemagick commands to write out labels, one of the labels I need to write is the following:

```
[0]
```

whenever I get to the command with this label it does not work.

This is the specific command

```
convert -background white -fill black -font Arial -pointsize 24 label:[0] -rotate 90 16.png
```

when I run this in my Mac terminal I get the message

```
convert: no images defined `16.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3282.
```

I have of course tried to escape with a backslash but neither

```
label:[0]
```

or

```
label:\[\0\]
```

or

```
label:[\0]
```

or

```
label:\[0\]
```

work, and each gives the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure about a Mac, but you may need two backslashes like... `\\[0\\]`. One for your shell and one for IM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
convert -pointsize 36 label:'\[0\]' image.png
```

The single quotes prevent the shell from seeing/interpreting the square brackets as a [bracket expression](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern) and the backslashes prevent **ImageMagick** from believing they are part of an `fx`-like expression.